# Incorrect syntax near ALTER NOCHECK CONSTRAINT - SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, bcp, alter

I am trying to disable a table's constraint with an ALTER statement using BCP commands. My code is as follows:

```
SET @disableConstraints = 'SQLCMD -E -S server-Name -d '+@databaseName+' -Q "EXEC sp_MSforeachtable @command1 = ALTER TABLE '+@schemaName+'.'+@tableName+' NOCHECK CONSTRAINT ALL;" >> Z:\Log\ErrorLog.txt'
```

However when I execute the `xp_cmdshell` command, the `ErrorLog.txt` will print an error saying:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Server server-Name, Line 1
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ALTER'.

I've been fiddling around with single quotes and double quotes, but I am not getting anywhere.

Can someone help spot the syntax error?

Comment: is it on A table (1) or all tables?

Comment: `EXEC sp_MSforeachtable @command1 = ALTER TABLE` - wouldn't you normally expect a string parameter being passed to a stored procedure to be *quoted*?

Comment: This command is executed within a cursor, so it is suppose to disable all constraints on 1 table and then loops to a second table and does the same thing.

Comment: is it on running on another server and the cursor on current db? or everything (cursor and alter) on the same db?

Comment: Cursor and alter on the same db

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Needed two single quotes at the start of ALTER and the end of ALL

```
SET @disableConstraints = 'SQLCMD -E -S server-Name -d '+@databaseName+' -Q "EXEC sp_MSforeachtable @command1 = ''ALTER TABLE '+@schemaName+'.'+@tableName+' NOCHECK CONSTRAINT ALL'';" >> Z:\Log\ErrorLog.txt'
```

Answer (score 0):

You miss the double quote before alter

```
SET @disableConstraints = 'SQLCMD -E -S server-Name -d ' + @databaseName + ' -Q EXEC sp_MSforeachtable @command1 = "ALTER TABLE ' + @schemaName + '.' + @tableName + ' NOCHECK CONSTRAINT ALL;" >> Z:\Log\ErrorLog.txt'
```

Answer (score 0):

In you cursor use only this query:

```
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max);
DECLARE tables_cursor FOR...
OPEN tables_cursor;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    PRINT QUOTENAME(@schemaName)+'.'+QUOTENAME(@tableName);
    set @sql = 'ALTER TABLE '+QUOTENAME(@schemaName)+'.'+QUOTENAME(@tableName)+' NOCHECK CONSTRAINT ALL;';
    EXEC sp_executesql @sql;

    FETCH NEXT FROM tables_cursor INTO @schemaName, @tableName;
END
CLOSE tables_cursor;
DEALLOCATE tables_cursor;
```

If all is executed on the same server and database, you don't need to use sqlcmd and connect to another server. Dynamic SQL with EXEC and [sp_executesql](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001(v=sql.120).aspx) will do it.